# Retrieve the last inserted record's ID in SQL Server CE 4

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I am trying to implement the good ol' SELECT `@@IDENTITY` like:

```
INSERT INTO NewsCategories (nCatName)
VALUES (@nCatName);
SELECT @@IDENTITY AS NewID;
```

But my SQL Server CE 4 is giving me the error:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 4,Token
>   line offset = 1,Token in error = SELECT ]

Is this something to do with the limitations of SQL Server CE? If so are there any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sql Server Compact Edition doesn't support batched queries, but you should be able to execute them one at a time and get what you're after.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but how exactly can I do that as I am using visual web developer's dataset designer. Do I create another SELECT query with @@IDENTITY and execute both insert and select in my codebehind?

Comment: I could not manage to do it. It returns null! hrrrrrrr. Would you be kind enough to give some code examples? Clicked and read nearly all of the google search results but don't seem to find a solution. All I want is to get the ID of the last inserted row.. this was piece of cake in sql server 20xx

Comment: @Emin Do you need to use the dataset designer for this?  Can you instead just run 2 ad-hoc queries in your codebehind?

Comment: Yes! That worked.. Thank you Fosco. It's a shame we have to go through this though!

Comment: You must run the "SELECT @@IDENTITY" against the same open connection that issued the INSERT statement